# How do you use concordion:run with parameters?

Tags: bdd, concordion

I would like to run a Concordion spec using a parameter. What I'd like to do is execute the spec using `concordion:run`. A [little research](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/concordion-dev/0yCSX9IIQ_s) pointed me to the existence of a `concordion:params` attribute, but I cannot find any documentation or examples.

I'm not sure how these two commands fit together; should the `params` element be nested inside the `run` element or outside? What is the value to fill in `concordion:params="?"` Where do I specify the param values themselves--in a `concordion:set` call?

Comment: Would you tell us a bit more about your use case? As noted below, we might deprecate concordion:params, and potentially replace it with something else in Concordion 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concordion:params` is an attribute to be used on the same element as the `concordion:run` attribute.

For example, in MyIndex.html:

```
<a concordion:run="concordion" concordion:params="foo=5" href="MySpec.html">My Spec</a>
```

with the fixture class:

```
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
@FullOGNL
public class MyIndex {
    public void setFoo(Integer foo) {
        System.out.println("foo = " + foo);
    }
}
```

Note that the `@FullOGNL` attribute is required to allow the syntax `foo=5` in the expression that wouldn't otherwise be allowed.

**NOTE:**
Tim Wright has [pointed out](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/concordion/UL0ksmhge7E/Z8UTJkmCMgAJ) an issue with this approach:

> The issue I see is that the same specification might be run from two
>   different specifications (or run twice from a single specification)
>   with different parameters as well as from jUnit with no parameters. As
>   we only create one HTML file, the behaviour might not be what the user
>   expects. It also means that using concordion:run will create a
>   different specification from running the spec directly as a jUnit test
>   - which is something we've tried hard to avoid.
>
> The current behaviour (with the concordion run cache) is that the
>   first one to be called will create the HTML file - and the second one
>   will return a run results from the cache thus ignoring the parameter.

This may mean that we deprecate concordion:params and remove it in 2.0.

Comment: I think this is the first documented usage of concordion:params. I'm not sure  if this is the intended usage, and have tweeted the original developer to find out.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's what you want since it's setting the value on the index specification rather than the specification that is being run. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: When I wrote that code way back I wanted it to be a way to build an overview page for your tests. The reason there is concordion:run="concordion" there is so you could even change the value with cubic test (a framework that I was working on at that time) or some other runner. Regarding the concordion:params I honestly think that I should have given them more consideration at the time. It is easy to say that look at it now. It be honest I don't think I used it more than a couple of times. It surely should have been documented with tests. I guess this wasn't much help.